# Routes not working in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a some very strange problem. I append new action to controller, register it in routing yml file. route:debug show it route as available. But when I try to go to this url I getting error about , that route does not exist. What I am doing wrong ? Old routes work proper.
This route catch route below:

```
vputi_company:
path:     /company/{company_id}
defaults: { _controller: VputiCompanyBundle:Company:showCompany, company_id: 0 }
```

Catched:

```
vputi_company_dashboard:
path:     /company/dashboard
defaults: { _controller: VputiCompanyBundle:Company:companyDashboard }
```

When I replace that and set it above all works properly.

Comment: please provide a little bit of code for inspect something... PS: if you are in prod environment try clearing the cache...

Comment: there is no interesting code to post. I cleared cache 1billion times. I try to change return of one action but it still return old results..

Comment: the order of the routes is also important, is there a chance that a previous route is catching the URL you are trying to process?

Comment: @Rooneyl, that solve my problem. But what, matter of the url order, both of the routes work related but diffrent things, how first route(action) can catch the second ?

Comment: @Panzer_Commander if you post your routes, I'll explain it in an answer

Comment: @Rooneyl, I added routes

Comment: @Panzer_Commander I have added an answer with an explanation for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes are processed as if they are a list, any like any computer function it tries to be efficient.
So when it finds a route that matches the given URL it runs that routes and then stops.

Your example routes;

```
vputi_company:
path:     /company/{company_id}
defaults: { _controller: VputiCompanyBundle:Company:showCompany, company_id: 0 }
vputi_company_dashboard:
path:     /company/dashboard
defaults: { _controller: VputiCompanyBundle:Company:companyDashboard }
```

In your example routes, the variable for `{company_id}` could be the string "*dashboard*", therefore fulfilling the first route as listed and not getting passed down to the next route (the one you want).

Reordered routes;

```
vputi_company_dashboard:
    path:     /company/dashboard
    defaults: { _controller: VputiCompanyBundle:Company:companyDashboard }
vputi_company:
    path:     /company/{company_id}
    defaults: { _controller: VputiCompanyBundle:Company:showCompany, company_id: 0 }
```

By re-ordering what you are kinda saying is match company with the string dashboard,if not then pass the second argument as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have forget Params in your route. (or maybe you add a un-need "/" at the end)

Also as Matteo said clear your cache (php app/console cache:clear) and provide us the code